# Compare Start Date/End Date get error on ModelState

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following in my model to compare start date and end date:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Missing start date entered.")]
    [CompareDates("EndDateTime", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a start date value that is earlier than the end date value.")]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date/Time")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> StartDateTime { get; set; }


    [CompareDates("StartDateTime", ErrorMessage = "Please enter an end date value that is later than the start date value.")]
    [Display(Name = "End Date/Time")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> EndDateTime { get; set; }
```

Even with my start date being before the end date, I get a ModelState.IsValid error: "Please enter a start date value that is earlier than the end date value. | Please enter an end date value that is later than the start date value." . Is there any way to get around this.

Comment: What is `CompareDates`? Is that third party?

Comment: Where is your `CompareDates` attribute code?

Comment: Please show your `CompareDatesAttribute` class. I believe that the code is created on your own, we need to know its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not got the rep to comment, so here's an "answer" instead...

Is the "CompareDates" attribute a custom one you've written?  Assuming it is, then it would be useful to have the code for this as well to help determine the cause of your error.